# AWS ECS fargate auto-scaling - how does it scale-in selects which tasks to terminate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling

I am running java process inside ecs fargate containers and have set-up auto scaling to scale-out when memory utilization is above 60% and scale-in accordingly. This setup is working fine but i am not able to figure out the criteria based upon which ecs determines which tasks it should shutdown as part of the scale-in events i.e how does it distinguishes between different tasks and picks one to shutdown ?
Does it check if there any active requests on the tasks or not and then if there are multiple such tasks then picks randomly ?

Comment: There is a concept of connection draining in load balancer. You can explore that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a **years long open issue** about that on github:

- [Control which containers are terminated on scale in](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/125)

From the issue and its comments you can infer the following:

> Does it check if there any active requests on the tasks

No.

> if there are multiple such tasks then picks randomly ?

Its random.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an update of this, now you can make your running task to be protected. Check this one for more details

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-fargate-service-auto-scaling/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

AWS announced a new feature in ECS called ECS scale-in protection in Nov 2022. This features determines that during the scale-out and scale-in it protects the tasks which are in process will be protected by ECS itself by evaluating this attribute `ProtectionEnabled == true` and then ECS will not terminate that task.

Refer below blog post by AWS. They have explained it clearly with use cases.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/announcing-amazon-ecs-task-scale-in-protection/